# Get selected checkbox values from ListView

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following markup in a ListView with a Checkbox object in each row - from this I'd like to find the selected checkbox values:

```
<asp:ListView ID="chkboxList" runat="server" DataKeyNames="id">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table id="audiencechklistbox" class="table table-striped  bootstrap-datatable datatable dataTable table-hover">
            <tr>
                <th>Audience Name</th>
            </tr>
            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="audienceList" value='<%# Eval("id") %>' Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' runat="server" CssClass="checkbox_nowrap"/>
        </td>
            </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I'm trying to use the following to find the Selected **value** of the checkboxes but can't seem to find a way to find anything other than the selected text.  I've looked at lots of similar questions here in SO, but can't seem to find one that matches my situation.

How do I find the selected value instead of the checkbox's displayed text?  My Lambda expression doesn't give me an Intellisense option for x.value.

```
        var findCheckedQuery = chkboxList.Controls[0]
            .Controls
            .Cast<Control>()
            .Select(ctrl => ctrl.FindControl("audienceList") as CheckBox)
            .Where(chk => chk != null && chk.Checked);                
            String[] result = findCheckedQuery.Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();
```

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server-side [CheckBox control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not expose such property as `value`, so what you have specified is treated as a custom attribute. To access it use:

```
x.Attributes["value"]
```

or (not sure which one will work)

```
x.InputAttributes["value"]
```

However since this is a custom attribute used for rendering only, I am not completely it will even be available on the post back to be accessed like that. As you can see, CheckBox control does not support values. Give it a try though anyway.

If it does not work, consider [HtmlInputCheckBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlinputcheckbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is slightly more limited control, but does provide necessary `Value` property. In markup this should be as simple as

```
<input ID="audienceList" Value='<%# Eval("id") %>' Text='<%# Eval("name") %>' runat="server" CssClass="checkbox_nowrap"/>
```

And in the code behind you of course need to change the class you cast controls to.

Comment: the x.Attributes["value"] worked.  I kept thinking I was going to need to look inside another method or property.  Thank you so much.